# SQL Server 2005 How to ignore errors during Create Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I need to create a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2005. Somewhere in the procedure, I have to join to a table which does not exist in the test environment but in the live environment (in a database in a linked server). I will not run the procedure in the test environment, but I need it to exist in order to create the ORM code in the application.

Naturally, SQL Server raises the error "Could not find server 'xxx' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedur sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.". However, I know that I can't add this server to the test environment, as it is not accessible from outside.

So, my question is, how can I create my stored procedure by ignoring the errors? Is there a way for it?

Comment: You should use a synonym instead of hard-coding the linked server name in your queries. In the test environment this allows you to just set the synonym to some local object, and in production it points to the actual linked server. Now the code in both places can be the same, because they're referencing the "same" synonym.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but if other people are having the same problem, here's another solution:

You can have your server via text and the procedure will pass.

```
create proc test
as    
declare @myserver varchar(50) = '[myserver\myinst]'
exec('select * from '+@myserver+'.dbo.table')
```

This way, the proc will compile on any environment, but will only run successfully on production

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that everything is correct and the procedure will work fine in live environment then create a fake linked server using `sp_addlinkedserver`.

What I mean is, if procedure body contains a linked server named `test_linked` and if it's not found then it will throw error.

Use `sp_addlinkedserver` and create a fake linked server named `test_linked` pointing to your test environment or even live environment. that will solve the issue cause it will try to check whether a linked server named `test_linked` does exist in `sys.servers` or not but unless you are running the procedure the actual linked server will not be accessed (AFAIK).

As [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) have mentioned in comment, Going by `synonym` would be a much cleaner approach though.

Comment: A synonym is a much, much, much cleaner approach.

Comment: I don't dare to disagree you :) but didn't got that idea out of my head. Answer edited to include what have you said in comment.

Comment: Thank you both. I'm gonna go with synonym as creating a fake linked server in a server that is not mine is not a good approach.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Now, the thing is, I am able to define the synonym even though I don't access it; however, when I try to create the procedure, I get the same error.

Comment: @ZaferSernikli, have you tried the approach I suggested? I know in presence of synonym this approach may not look good but it definitely works. Moreover, even though the server not yours, just creating a linked server won't harm anything.

Comment: @ZaferSemikli what is the synonym you created? On the server without the right linked server, does it point to a valid object that exists locally? Did you change the stored procedure code to reference the synonym instead of the linked server?

Comment: @AaronBertrand The synonym does not point to a valid object. That's why I can create it but cannot use it. Actually, the problem itself is that the object does not exist locally, but I want my procedure to be created even though it does not work. 

And Rahul, I commented out the join and the the selected columns instead of it. Creating a fake linked server in developement server is not a good idea even though it would work and does not harm; because if everyone did it, the server would be mess.

Comment: @Zafer My point was: create a synonym on the test box that POINTS to something REAL and LOCAL that won't fail validation. This will allow your procedure to be created, and will prevent you from having to add/remove comments every time you change the procedure and deploy it. THAT is a mess.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Well, then it needs to have the columns that I try to pull as well and this is not practically different than just creating a table with the same structure.

Comment: @Zafer there's a big difference: a local table you create can hide behind the synonym without having to use a four-part name in the code. What I'm trying to show you is you can create this dummy table and a synonym *once* to avoid all this commenting and other jazz *every time you deploy.* If you don't see the benefit in that, *shrug*, I give up, have a great day.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I totally understand and see the benefit in that. With "practically different" I didn't mean that it was not more practical, but it was a solution which leads to the same thing. I was actually looking for some option or configuration to allow sql server to save the non-working sp. Thanks for the synonym suggestion. I am going to use it somewhere for sure.